# Change images with jquery based on json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm fiddling with jquery and json, basically trying to make a weather app. I want to display gifs according to the data.

Example data coming from the API:

```
"time": 1468261711,
"summary": "Clear",
"icon": "clear-day",
```

I know the possible values already so I want to make an array like if the summary object is "Clear", display sunny.gif.

What would be a common method of achieving this?

Comment: could you please provide a few more relevant code samples to clarify what  you want to achieve?

Comment: not really following what you're trying to do here - can you be more specific?

Comment: Question updated. Sorry if it didn't make sense before.

Comment: A possible implementation would be to parse the JSON into a JS object using JSON.parse(jsonString); Then you simple check the summary property of the Object to get the value and display the gif you want. I could post some code if this is the implementation you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more example code, it's hard to advise on the best solution.

You can create an object with keys that reference the summary and values that point to the GIF.

ie:

```
var gifs = {
    "Clear": "clear.gif",
    "Sunny": "sunny.gif"
};
```

Now when you parse through the data from the API. You can get the relevant GIF.

```
var weatherObject = {
    "time": 1468261711,
    "summary": "Clear",
    "icon": "clear-day"
}

var gif = gifs[weatherObject.summary]; // Returns clear.gif
```

Read more about JS Objects [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp).

Comment: This is a straightforward method that I was able to implement. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can have a hash object that maps the weather summary to the gif like:

```
var map = {
    "Cloudy": {
        "media": "../images/weather-cloudy.gif"
    },
    "Clear": {
        "media": "../images/weather-sunny.gif"
    }
};
```

On your API ajax callback you could render based on this map info:

```
$.get("api/weather?q=Newyork")
    .done(function (data) {

        var html = yourHandlebarsCompiledTemplateForExample({
           apiData: data,
           mappedInfo: map[data.summary]
        });

        $(html).appendTo("#weather-contanier");
    });
```

Comment: if you are not aware of Handlebars take a look at: http://handlebarsjs.com/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will definitely check it out.